# How to highlight the matching sub-string from search result in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a newbie in JavaScript. Trying to build a small user interface that searches a list of words when we fire a query into the search box. With that, I want to highlight the matching sub-string of each word in the list box so that the user can see at a glance how the word matches the query. To achieve this target I include **highlight** function in my code by referring some basic JS tutorials. But due to some mistake, it is not working. Can you please help me. Thanks..!!!

```
    function getFullName(item,index) { 
        return "<li>"+item.firstname + "<span class='tool-tip'>" +item.lastname+"</span> "+ item.id+"</li>";
    }
    function myFunction1() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = persons.map(getFullName);
    }

    function myFunction() {
        var input, filter, ul, li, a, i,count=0;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();

      var longWords = persons.filter(function(person){

         return  person.firstname.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 
    });
        var message = "Result:" + longWords.length + " words containing '" + input.value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=message;

        ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
        ul.innerHTML= longWords.map(getFullName);
        highlight();
    }
    function highlight(){
        var inputText, filter1,innerHTML,index;
        inputText = document.getElementById("myInput");
        console.log(inputText);
        filter1 = inputText.value.toUpperCase();
        console.log(filter1);
        innerHTML1 = inputText.innerHTML;
        console.log(innerHTML1);
        index1 = innerHTML1.indexOf(filter1);
    if ( index1 >= 0 )
    { 
        innerHTML1 = innerHTML1.substring(0,index1) + "<span class='highlight'>" + innerHTML1.substring(index1,index1+filter1.length) + "</span>" + innerHTML1.substring(index1 + filter1.length);
        filter1.innerHTML = innerHTML1; 
    }

}
```

here is the CSS file:

```
.highlight{
             font-weight:bold;
             color:black;
 }
```

Comment: First of all, without a [mcve], nobody can understand what's wrong with your code. Secondly, you probably need to learn to use `console.log(stuff)` in your code, where `stuff` is what you are interested in at that particular point in code. If you follow the log by `debugger;` command, JavaScript will be interrupted at that particular point in code and you can use the console to give commands at that point.

Comment: @Andrei Gheorghiu: According to your suggestions, I edited the code. After debugging I found when the control goes in **if** it gets stuck. There are two possibilities, either the logic is wrong or maybe I made mistake while replacing index to **index1** and innerHTML to **innerHTML1**. Hence it is not working

Comment: `index = innerHTML1.indexOf(filter1);
    if ( index >= 0 )
    { 
        innerHTML1 = innerHTML1.substring(0,index) + "<span class='highlight'>" + innerHTML1.substring(index,index+filter1.length) + "</span>" + innerHTML1.substring(index + filter1.length);
        filter1.innerHTML = innerHTML1; 
    }`

Comment: Is this right??

Comment: the code for reference is here: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/j5294dvr/3/)

Answer (score 3):

Following is from my bookmarked code for highlighting. Type a text in textfield and you can see the highligted text in yellow

```js
function highlight_text_nodes($nodes, word) {
  if (!$nodes.length) {
    return;
  }

  var text = '';

  // Concatenate the consecutive nodes to get the actual text
  for (var i = 0; i < $nodes.length; i++) {
    text += $nodes[i].textContent;
  }

  var $fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

  while (true) {
    // Tweak this if you want to change the highlighting behavior
    var index = text.toLowerCase().indexOf(word.toLowerCase());

    if (index === -1) {
      break;
    }

    // Split the text into [before, match, after]
    var before = text.slice(0, index);
    var match = text.slice(index, index + word.length);
    text = text.slice(index + word.length);

    // Create the <mark>
    var $mark = document.createElement('mark');
    $mark.className = 'found';
    $mark.appendChild(document.createTextNode(match));

    // Append it to the fragment
    $fragment.appendChild(document.createTextNode(before));
    $fragment.appendChild($mark);
  }

  // If we have leftover text, just append it to the end
  if (text.length) {
    $fragment.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
  }

  // Replace the nodes with the fragment
  $nodes[0].parentNode.insertBefore($fragment, $nodes[0]);

  for (var i = 0; i < $nodes.length; i++) {
    var $node = $nodes[$nodes.length - i - 1];
    $node.parentNode.removeChild($node);
  }
}


/*
 * Highlights all instances of `word` in `$node` and its children
 */
function highlight($node, word) {
  var $children = $node.childNodes;
  var $current_run = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < $children.length; i++) {
    var $child = $children[i];

    if ($child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      // Keep track of consecutive text nodes
      $current_run.push($child);
    } else {
      // If we hit a regular element, highlight what we have and start over
      highlight_text_nodes($current_run, word);
      $current_run = [];

      // Ignore text inside of our <mark>s
      if ($child.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && $child.className !== 'found') {
        highlight($child, word);
      }
    }
  }

  // Just in case we have only text nodes as children
  if ($current_run.length) {
    highlight_text_nodes($current_run, word);
  }
}

/*
 * Removes all highlighted <mark>s from the given node
 */
function unhighlight($node) {
  var $marks = [].slice.call($node.querySelectorAll('mark.found'));

  for (var i = 0; i < $marks.length; i++) {
    var $mark = $marks[i];

    // Replace each <mark> with just a text node of its contents
    $mark.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode($mark.childNodes[0].textContent), $mark);
  }
}



var $p = document.querySelector('p');

document.querySelector('input').onkeyup = function() {
  unhighlight($p);

  if (this.value.length) {
    highlight($p, this.value);
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="text" />

<p>
<b>JavaScript</b> is a high-level, dynamic, multi-paradigm, object-oriented, prototype-based, weakly-typed language traditionally used for client-side scripting in web browsers. JavaScript can also be run outside of the browser with the use of a framework like Node.js, Nashorn, Wakanda, or Google Apps Script. Despite the name, it is unrelated to the Java programming language and shares only superficial similarities.

Unless a tag for a framework or library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected for questions with the javascript tag.
</p>
```

> Edit, based on comment. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j5294dvr/4/) version for OP.

The jsfiddle version just tweek OP's code to give her an insight of how it works

Comment: good example, but try to solve the problem according to OP's perspective. Try to update the code given in the question.

Comment: @Optional: How to run your code offline?? I think I am missing something. I copy pasted your code in .html and .js files locally on my machine. But it is not showing output as above( _code snippet_)

Comment: Or can you please check the logic of my **if loop**??  As you Split the text into [before, match, after] I try to do the similar thing in my code

Comment: To run the code locally, create a .html file, `<html <body></body></html>` and in between body, add the html code from input to </p>. After that add a tag `<script></script>` tag and copy the javascript code and open html in browser.

Comment: @Rupali I need your html snippet/code to try the javascript, else i will have to create one.

Comment: @Rupali First of all, Your onLoad itself was not getting called. I updated the script . https://jsfiddle.net/j5294dvr/3/  so that at least your functions are called. Now there are multiple problems with your code. You can log/alert your index to find out that "index" is always <0 so that your code is not getting executed. You are "using" inputText.innerHTML as string to find the index, while it shall be the inner text of "<li>" elements. In this version 3 of jsfiddle, you can put log/alert to your highlight method to see if your "search" itself is working. Your getFullName is working fine

Comment: @Rupali here is the modified working version of your script https://jsfiddle.net/j5294dvr/4/ I used the method that you are using to create ordered list, to highlight. Now you know what I meant, and you can adapt accordingly